# Insert xml to <select>

Tags: jquery, html, xml, jquery-selectors

XML:

```
<Questions>

  <Question>
     <Id>1</Id>
     <Text>aaa</Text>
     <Reserver />
  </Question>

  <Question>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Text>bbb</Text>
    <Reserver />
  </Question>

</Questions>
```

Script

```
$(doc).find("Questions").each(function()
{
  $('#s').
  append( $("<option></option>").
          attr("value",$(this).find('Text').text()).
          text($(this).find('Text').text())); 

});
```

HTML

```
 <select id="s">
     <option></option>
 </select>
```

I'd like to add `'aaa'` and `'bbb'` to select that name "s" in new line.

But this code add `aaa bbb` to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `find("Questions")` to `find("Question")` to loop through the individual `<Question>` elements instead of the single `<Questions>` element.

Also, you should call `$.parseXML`.